# Trying to download USB version of SmartOS -- no go

Tags: smartos

I'm trying to download the USB version of SmartOS based on instructions here:

http://wiki.smartos.org/display/DOC/Download+SmartOS

This seems to download two images:

smartos-latest-USB.img.bz2

smartos-latest-USB.img.bz2.part

When I bunzip2 smartos-latest-USB.img.bz2 I get the following error:

bunzip2: Compressed file ends unexpectedly;
    perhaps it is corrupted?  *Possible* reason follows.
bunzip2: No such file or directory
    Input file = smartos-latest-USB.img.bz2, output file = smartos-latest-USB.img

It is possible that the compressed file(s) have become corrupted.

I've retried the download several times with the same error.

So, questions:

- Why two files?
- How can I get SmartOS on my USB stick?

Many thanks,

LRP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file never finished downloading.   "smartos-latest-USB.img.bz2.part" is the temporary file created by your browser; Firefox in this case.  You should end up with a single image that can be written to your USB drive.

Try the process again.

Comment: Many thanks for the response. I finally got it working by reinstalling bzip2.